# sharedfilelistd and distnoted hog CPU

Tags: macos, performance, cpu

I understand from my findings on the topic that sharedfilelistd is an "agent that is used by applications to read/modify recent documents/servers/hosts" and distnoted a "distributed notification services".

What I don't understand is why those two process very frequently start using between 130 and 200% of CPU (Monitor).

I tried various combinations of apps loaded or not that would be causing the problem, but I was unable to discern a pattern.

I can't tie this issue with any noticeable event (update, install, config tweak, ...).

Any idea ? (while I continue looking into possible causes)

Config:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)
High Sierra 10.13.4
2,2 GHz Intel Core i7
8 Go 1600 MHz DDR3
Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 Mo

Comment: To rule out if these have legitimate work to do, what happens if you disconnect all network connections and restart the Mac. These daemons should process all remaining work and then be mostly idle 20 minutes after you log in.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I've just had this happen for the first time, and I'm in Singapore for the first time. Is this a coincidence?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with `sharedfilelistd` consistently taking over 100% of my CPU. I don't have file sharing enabled.

I opened up Terminal and found the processes with `pgrep -lf sharedfilelistd`, noticing two of them running; that might have indicated a problem. I killed both with `sudo pkill sharedfilelistd` and they terminated and one restarted, presumably via launchd.

After the single process returned, it took between 30-75% of my CPU, perhaps averaging 50%, and my machine is back to normal. There might be some impact to some service I'm not aware of or do not use, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Relaunching the Finder helped for me.

Comment: Yes, it did! Mojave 10.14.6. 
Now I only have to solve why *kernel_task* has written 3.5 TB to the system ssd.

Comment: @JavierRuiz Did you find out? I’m having the exact same issue. The only thing I could find in the Console was that somehow “Amazon Music Helper” was being launched and crashing over and over again, and writing crash reports. Weird, and definitely a problem (I don’t use Amazon Music!) but these don’t account for the large amount of data being written to SSD.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm...actually I installed Amazon Music some time ago... So far I haven't been able to track the cause of this huge writing to disk.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen similar symptoms but my solution was different.

I had the high CPU usage on **sharedfilelistd** but my Trash was empty, so emptying it wasn't an option. Then I noticed that **Preview** was also using a lot of CPU and when I checked it had a couple of images open from a shared folder.

Quitting **Preview** from **Activity Monitor** then

So, I *think* the underlying issue is if an application has a shared file open it can lead to **sharedfilelistd** running hot. Stopping this application releases the lock (or whatever the root cause is). It doesn't seem to happen immediately, only if a file is open for a while.

Config: Mojave 10.14.6 (18G2022), MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015), 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7, AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2 GB/Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB.

Comment: Thanks. I started quitting unused apps and it seemed like Finder was the offender in my case. Mid 2017 15" MacBook Pro/ Mojave 10.14.6 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, which I solved when I emptied the Trash

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and taking the time to post an answer!  It's helpful to *expand* on your answer to further explain/clarify what you are attempting to communicate.

Comment: Answer seems complete to me. Succinct. Also appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, I also encountered this problem, which made my CPU use up to 130%, but it seems to be temporary. There is also a distnoted process which also occupies a very high cpu

I shut down the file sharing and remote combo in the preferences and the two processes automatically exited

Comment: 欢迎来到 Ask Different! 请注意这里是英语社区，所以请用英语发表内容。 / Welcome to Ask Different! Please note this is an English-only community, so please post in English.

Comment: I shut down the file sharing and remote combo in the preferences and the two processes automatically exited.

Comment: I've turned off all sharing in system prefs and still very high cpu. Will restart and see what happens.

Comment: I see no effect turning off all sharing either.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity monitor, find the process with `com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService (Finder)` or  `com.apple.appkit.xpc.openAndSavePanelService (Mail)` as the name.

Kill the process in the parentheses: `killall Mail` or `killall Finder`

I don't know the reason, but it just works.